# neglect inner tag in XmlPullParser android

Tags: android, html, tags, xmlpullparser

```
<p>The Dog sports Sports like <em> agility </em>, flyball, obedience, rally obedience, musical freestyle and tracking can give you and your dog a whole new world of fun exercise and competition to explore. <strong>Activities</strong> for specific breed groups include herding, lure coursing, hunt tests and go-to-ground trials. For more information on these and other sports, </p>
```

i want to get all text inside the paragraph tag (like below) but it give error on (em tag) " parser.nextText(); "
can any one know how to do this , thanks in advance.

The Dog sports Sports like agility , flyball, obedience, rally obedience, musical freestyle and tracking can give you and your dog a whole new world of fun exercise and competition to explore. Activities for specific breed groups include herding, lure coursing, hunt tests and go-to-ground trials. For more information on these and other sports,

here is code

```
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = null;

            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    Drugs = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("p"))
                    {

                        String s=parser.nextText();


                    }
                break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
```

here is log

11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: END_TAG expected (position:START_TAG @47:333 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4b9110e) 
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:2086)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at com.magsol.drugdictionary.Detail.parseXML(Detail.java:227)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at com.magsol.drugdictionary.Detail.onCreate(Detail.java:116)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
11-24 19:22:01.357: W/System.err(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)